# how to store objects into hashmap as key and its insert into asending order without using comparator and comprable

Tags: java, hashmap, logic, hashcode

I want to store Objects in the Hash map as key and while Retrieving time  i want  a ascending order based on Employee id.and i dont want to use comparator or comaprable interfaces just sorting based on hashcode and equals method is it possible.

```
 public class Employee {

private String name;
private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
//  result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    System.out.println("hashcode value :::"+result + "id :::"+id);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

```
package info.test;

 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Set;

  public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setId(2);
    e1.setName("name");
    Employee e2 = new Employee();
    e2.setId(35);
    e2.setName("name");
    Employee e3 = new Employee();
    e3.setId(4);
    e3.setName("name");
    Employee e4 = new Employee();
    e4.setId(3);
    e4.setName("name");

    Map<Employee, String> linkedHashMap = new HashMap<Employee,String>();
    linkedHashMap.put(e1, "e");
    linkedHashMap.put(e2, "e");
    linkedHashMap.put(e3, "e");
    linkedHashMap.put(e4, "e");


     Set<Employee> keySet = linkedHashMap.keySet();
     for(Employee e:keySet){
        //System.out.println(e.getId()); 
     }


}}
```

**its work some samples like**

```
 if give ids like 2 55 4 3  and output is 2 3 4 55
```

**and for some samples its not working**

```
 2 35 4 3  and output 2 35 3 4
```

Comment: No, it's not. A HashMap is not a sorted map, and if you used a sorted map, you would need a comparator, because you can't tell whether somthing is bigger, lower or equal to something else without that.

Comment: `just sorting based on hashcode and equals method`. How would that be? `hashCode` returns a value that is used to scatter the entries along the internal array that comprises a `HashMap`, while `equals` compares two objects for *equality* and returns a `boolean`, saying whether the objects are equal or not. How would you sort based on these two methods, if you are never saying which object should come before the other? I mean, you need to *compare* if you want some sorting to occur. This is basic maths and basic common sense. You can't sort based on equality and a value used to separate stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You were **so** close. This

```
Map<Employee, String> linkedHashMap = new HashMap<Employee,String>();
```

should be [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which preserved *insertion order* like

```
Map<Employee, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

If it should be *sorted* in *natural order* use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) like

```
Map<Employee, String> linkedHashMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer if a use TreeMap then i need to implement comparable interface to employee class but i dont want like that ,its any possible to do sorting with hashcode and equals method

Comment: @Raju *its any possible to do sorting with hashcode and equals method* **No**. For hashcode to work properly the hashes must be well distributed. That means they are **fundamentally** not usable for sorting.

Comment: @Raju how would you do sorting based on hashCode and equals? If two objects the have the same hashCode, but are equal - which one goes first? You could just create a comparator and point it to the hashCode, but are the values sorted by this any better than being random?